# MongoDB - Index Intersection with two multikey indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two arrays in my collection (one is an embedded document and the other one is just a simple collection of strings). A document for example:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("534fb7b4f9591329d5ea3d0c"),
    "_class" : "discussion",
    "title" : "A",
    "owner" : "1",
    "tags" : ["tag-1", "tag-2", "tag-3"],
    "creation_time" : ISODate("2014-04-17T11:14:59.777Z"),
    "modification_time" : ISODate("2014-04-17T11:14:59.777Z"),
    "policies" : [
        {
            "participant_id" : "2",
            "action" : "CREATE"
        }, {
            "participant_id" : "1",
            "action" : "READ"
        }
    ]
}
```

Since some of the queries will include only the policies and some will include the tags and the participants arrays, and considering the fact that I can't create an multikey indexe with two arrays, I thought that it will be a classic scenario to use the [Index Intersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/).

I'm executing a query , but I can't see the intersection kicks in.

Here are the indexes:

```js
db.discussion.getIndexes()

   {
           "v" : 1,
           "key" : {
                   "_id" : 1
           },
           "name" : "_id_",
           "ns" : "test-fw.discussion"
   },
   {
           "v" : 1,
           "key" : {
                   "tags" : 1,
                   "creation_time" : 1
           },
           "name" : "tags",
           "ns" : "test-fw.discussion",
           "dropDups" : false,
           "background" : false
   },
   {
           "v" : 1,
           "key" : {
                   "policies.participant_id" : 1,
                   "policies.action" : 1
           },
           "name" : "policies",
           "ns" : "test-fw.discussion"
   }
```

Here is the query:

```js
db.discussion.find({ 
    "$and" : [ 
        { "tags" : { "$in" : [ "tag-1" , "tag-2" , "tag-3"] }},
        { "policies" : { "$elemMatch" : { 
            "$and" : [ 
                { "participant_id" : { "$in" : [ 
                    "participant-1",
                    "participant-2", 
                    "participant-3"
                ]}}, 
                { "action" : "READ"}
            ]
        }}}
    ]
})
.limit(20000).sort({ "creation_time" : 1 }).explain();
```

And here is the result of the explain:

```js
      "clauses" : [
          {
                  "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags",
                  "isMultiKey" : true,
                  "n" : 10000,
                  "nscannedObjects" : 10000,
                  "nscanned" : 10000,
                  "scanAndOrder" : false,
                  "indexOnly" : false,
                  "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                  "indexBounds" : {
                          "tags" : [
                                  [
                                          "tag-1",
                                          "tag-1"
                                  ]
                          ],
                          "creation_time" : [
                                  [
                                          {
                                                  "$minElement" : 1
                                          },
                                          {
                                                  "$maxElement" : 1
                                          }
                                  ]
                          ]
                  }
          },
          {
                  "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags",
                  "isMultiKey" : true,
                  "n" : 10000,
                  "nscannedObjects" : 10000,
                  "nscanned" : 10000,
                  "scanAndOrder" : false,
                  "indexOnly" : false,
                  "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                  "indexBounds" : {
                          "tags" : [
                                  [
                                          "tag-2",
                                          "tag-2"
                                  ]
                          ],
                          "creation_time" : [
                                  [
                                          {
                                                  "$minElement" : 1
                                          },
                                          {
                                                  "$maxElement" : 1
                                          }
                                  ]
                          ]
                  }
          },
          {
                  "cursor" : "BtreeCursor tags",
                  "isMultiKey" : true,
                  "n" : 10000,
                  "nscannedObjects" : 10000,
                  "nscanned" : 10000,
                  "scanAndOrder" : false,
                  "indexOnly" : false,
                  "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                  "indexBounds" : {
                          "tags" : [
                                  [
                                          "tag-3",
                                          "tag-3"
                                  ]
                          ],
                          "creation_time" : [
                                  [
                                          {
                                                  "$minElement" : 1
                                          },
                                          {
                                                  "$maxElement" : 1
                                          }
                                  ]
                          ]
                  }
          }
  ],
  "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
  "n" : 20000,
  "nscannedObjects" : 30000,
  "nscanned" : 30000,
  "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 30203,
  "nscannedAllPlans" : 30409,
  "scanAndOrder" : false,
  "nYields" : 471,
  "nChunkSkips" : 0,
  "millis" : 165,
  "server" : "User-PC:27017",
  "filterSet" : false
```

Each of the tags in the query (tag1, tag-2 and tag-3 ) have 10K documents.
Each of the policies ({participant-1,READ},{participant-2,READ},{participant-3,READ}) have 10K documents.

The AND operator results with 20K documents.

As I said earlier, I can't see why the intersection of the two indexes (I mean the policies and the tags indexes), doesn't kick in.

Can someone please shade some light on the thing that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that are actually important to your understanding of this.

- The first point is that the query optimizer can only use **one** index when resolving the query plan and cannot use both of the indexes you have specified. As such it picks the one that is the best "fit" by it's own determination, unless you explicitly specify this with a [`hint`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor-hint). Intersection somewhat suits, but now for the next point:
- The second point is documented in the [limitations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#limitations) of compound indexes. This actually points out that even if you were to "try" to create a compound index that included both of the array fields you want, then you could not. The problem here is that as an array this introduces too many possibilities for the bounds keys, and a multi-key index already introduces a fair level of complexity when used in compound with a standard field.

The limitations on combining the two multi-key indexes is the main problem here, much as it is on creation, the complexity of "combining" the two produces two many permutations to make it a viable option.

It might just be the case that the `policies` index is actually going to be the better one to use for this type of search, and you could probably amend this by specifying that field in the query first:

```js
db.discussion.find({
    { 
        "policies" : { "$elemMatch" : { 
            "participant_id" : { "$in" : [ 
                "participant-1", 
                "participant-2",
                "participant-3"
            ]},
            "action" : "READ"
        }},
        "tags" : { "$in" : [ "tag-1" , "tag-2" , "tag-3"] }
    }
)
```

That is if that will select the smaller range of data, which it probably does. Otherwise use the [`hint`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor-hint) modifier as mentioned earlier.

If that does not actually directly help results, it might be worth re-considering the schema to something that would not involve having those values in array fields or some other type of "meta" field that could be easily looked up with an index.

Also note in the edited form that all the wrapping **`$and`** statements should not be required as "and" is implicit in MongoDB queries. As a modifier it is only required if you want **two** *different* conditions on the same field.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Just to make it cleare, I'm talking about the Index Intersection feature (new in 2.6) . The limitations on the compound index are quite cleare. I don't see any limitations on the Index Intersection documentation (the direct link is on the initial question).I still can not find the relation between the compound index limitation and my usecase. Can you please share with me a resource that can explain it?

Comment: @MordechaiTamam Understood, but the underlying principles are the same when dealing with Multi-key indexes. I don't think the current methods of intersection are quite up to dealing with various Multi-key indexes. This is a concept borrowed from the relational world where the concept of something like Multi-key does not exist. Hence why I draw the comparison to a compound index as the general principle is the same.

Comment: @MordechaiTamam Been working on other things, so a delay. But for a little more clarification (and sadly there is not a hard reference for this, as is generally the case with new things) but consider something like a text or geo-spatial index. How would you propose those indexes would be meant to intersect, as in the use of two or more of those (if it were even possible to issue that query)? We are really talking about the same basic thing, in that these complex types to not lend well to the principles of index intersection. It would be nice, but I'm glad I'm not writing the code for it.

Comment: Thanks, I hope that we'll be able to get concrete answers from one of MongoDB engineers (no offence :) )

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little testing, I believe Mongo can, in fact, use two multikey indexes in an intersection. I created a collection with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e129c90ab3dc0006000001"),
    "bar" : [
        "hgcmdflitt",
        ...
        "nuzjqxmzot"
    ],
    "foo" : [
        "bxzvqzlpwy",
        ...
        "xcwrwluxbd"
    ]
}
```

I created indexes on foo and bar and then ran the following query. Note the "true" passed in to explain. This enables verbose mode.

```
db.col.find({"bar":"hgcmdflitt", "foo":"bxzvqzlpwy"}).explain(true)
```

In the verbose results, you can find the "allPlans" section of the response, which will show you all of the query plans mongo considered.

```
"allPlans" : [
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor bar_1",
        ...
    },
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor foo_1",
        ...
    },
    {
        "cursor" : "Complex Plan"
        ...
    }
]
```

If you see a plan with "cursor" : "Complex Plan" that means mongo [considered using an index intersection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/). To find the reasons why mongo might not have decided to actually use that query plan, see this answer: [Why doesn't MongoDB use index intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786853/why-doesnt-mongodb-use-index-intersection)

Comment: You can read here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#interactions-between-compound-and-multikey-indexes about the limitations. It strictly says "...at most one field in a compound index may hold an array."