# MongoDB index strategy for time based data

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-performance

Our mongodb collection (version 3.6.1) used for monitoring events has 15 columns and contains approx. 10 Million records. 
The document structure is similar to the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b56f26fa8b7ce5274deb72e"),
    "headers" : "",
    "message2Id" : "cdf6a0bd-0a48-47ed-9444-6a7d79864bc2",
    "activity" : "request_out",
    "originator" : "",
    "serviceName" : "myServiceA",
    "sequenceName" : "mySequenceA",
    "messageUnid" : "urn:uuid:934b3bda-0733-4702-aebe-0844ec72e43a",
    "node" : "INT_WRK1",
    "payload" : "",
    "details" : "messageDetails”
    "processType" : "typeA",
    "time" : NumberLong(1532424815712),
    "status" : "200",
    "timeDateFormat" : ISODate("2018-07-24T09:33:35.712Z")
}
```

Most queries are based on the combination of time column (time interval) + one or more other columns (eg. service name, sequence name, status etc.). The combination of those “other” columns depends on user’s choice. 
The problem is poor performance of this kind of queries; some of these queries typically end up with timeout.

The queries implement paging (using skip and limit methods) and the application also displays number of records passing the criteria (makes "count" using aggregation command). Even this simple “count” takes too long and – as a workaround – we had to add $limit :100 stage into aggregation command (resulting in displaying exact values up to 100 and then “> 100”)

The amount of RAM available for mongodb instance is approx. 12 GB.

The question is how to improve performance and what is the best index strategy for this case ?

1.) Separate indexes on individual columns and relay on index intersection ? But accrding to this post [Why doesn't MongoDB use index intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786853/why-doesnt-mongodb-use-index-intersection) won’t work for time interval

2.) Compound indexes for each combination time + {one other column} ? But will these indexes be sufficiently selective for all situations (e.g. status column) ?

3.) Compound indexes for each combination time + { permutations of all other columns }  - But there are too many possible combinations and we can easily run out for RAM

4.) Any other idea ?

Thanks 
Vaclav