# How to check if index intersection can support a query in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, database-indexes

tl;dr

1. I've set up indices that can be used as an index intersection for my query
2. Query planner does not prefer an intersection due to insufficient data
3. Now I need a stable way to verify the **correctness** of this **potential** intersection plan just like using `explain()` `hint()` for single index setups

I fully understand why index intersection is not preferred atm and may actually not be preferred in most cases. But I'm simply looking for a method to verify index intersections in general.

========

I've got a `notifications` collection which holds documents such as

```js
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5cdd1819c1136c394a052aa2"),
    "notifiable": DBRef("users", ObjectId("5cdd172ac1136c1bdc06bdf2")),
    "read_at": ISODate("2019-05-16T07:59:17.985Z")
}
```

...and it's got the following indices:

```js
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "notifiable.$id" : 1,
            "notifiable.$ref" : 1,
            "created_at" : -1,
            "updated_at" : -1
        },
        "name" : "notifiable.$id_1_notifiable.$ref_1_created_at_-1_updated_at_-1",
        "ns" : "example.notifications"
},
{
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "read_at" : 1
        },
        "name" : "read_at_1",
        "ns" : "example.notifications"
    }
]
```

When I run queries e.g.

```js
db.notifications.find({ read_at: { $gt: ISODate("2019-05-16T07:55:57.799Z") }, "notifiable.$id": ObjectId("5cdd172ac1136c1bdc06bdf2") })
```

...I expect MongoDB to use an intersection of these two indices when needed. But since [MongoDB takes a lot of factors into consideration to determine whether an intersection of indices should be used](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071?focusedCommentId=508454&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-508454), only 1 index was used for my query (perhaps because there were only a few documents in the collection) and even the result of `explain(true)` didn't have any `AND_SORTED` `AND_HASH` stage:

```js
{
    "queryPlanner": {
        "plannerVersion": 1,
        "namespace": "example.notifications",
        "indexFilterSet": false,
        "parsedQuery": {
            "$and": [{
                    "notifiable.$id": {
                        "$eq": ObjectId("5cdd172ac1136c1bdc06bdf2")
                    }
                },
                {
                    "read_at": {
                        "$gt": ISODate("2019-05-16T07:55:57.799Z")
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "filter": {
                "notifiable.$id": {
                    "$eq": ObjectId("5cdd172ac1136c1bdc06bdf2")
                }
            },
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern": {
                    "read_at": 1
                },
                "indexName": "read_at_1",
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                    "read_at": []
                },
                "isUnique": false,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "indexVersion": 2,
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                    "read_at": [
                        "(new Date(1557993357799), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans": [{
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "filter": {
                "read_at": {
                    "$gt": ISODate("2019-05-16T07:55:57.799Z")
                }
            },
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern": {
                    "notifiable.$id": 1,
                    "notifiable.$ref": 1,
                    "created_at": -1,
                    "updated_at": -1
                },
                "indexName": "notifiable.$id_1_notifiable.$ref_1_created_at_-1_updated_at_-1",
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                    "notifiable.$id": [],
                    "notifiable.$ref": [],
                    "created_at": [],
                    "updated_at": []
                },
                "isUnique": false,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "indexVersion": 2,
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                    "notifiable.$id": [
                        "[ObjectId('5cdd172ac1136c1bdc06bdf2'), ObjectId('5cdd172ac1136c1bdc06bdf2')]"
                    ],
                    "notifiable.$ref": [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "created_at": [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ],
                    "updated_at": [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "executionStats": {
        "executionSuccess": true,
        "nReturned": 1,
        "executionTimeMillis": 0,
        "totalKeysExamined": 2,
        "totalDocsExamined": 2,
        "executionStages": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "filter": {
                "notifiable.$id": {
                    "$eq": ObjectId("5cdd172ac1136c1bdc06bdf2")
                }
            },
            "nReturned": 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
            "works": 4,
            "advanced": 1,
            "needTime": 1,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 0,
            "restoreState": 0,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "invalidates": 0,
            "docsExamined": 2,
            "alreadyHasObj": 0,
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned": 2,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                "works": 3,
                "advanced": 2,
                "needTime": 0,
                "needYield": 0,
                "saveState": 0,
                "restoreState": 0,
                "isEOF": 1,
                "invalidates": 0,
                "keyPattern": {
                    "read_at": 1
                },
                "indexName": "read_at_1",
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                    "read_at": []
                },
                "isUnique": false,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "indexVersion": 2,
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                    "read_at": [
                        "(new Date(1557993357799), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined": 2,
                "seeks": 1,
                "dupsTested": 0,
                "dupsDropped": 0,
                "seenInvalidated": 0
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution": [{
                "nReturned": 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                "totalKeysExamined": 2,
                "totalDocsExamined": 2,
                "executionStages": {
                    "stage": "FETCH",
                    "filter": {
                        "notifiable.$id": {
                            "$eq": ObjectId("5cdd172ac1136c1bdc06bdf2")
                        }
                    },
                    "nReturned": 1,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                    "works": 3,
                    "advanced": 1,
                    "needTime": 1,
                    "needYield": 0,
                    "saveState": 0,
                    "restoreState": 0,
                    "isEOF": 1,
                    "invalidates": 0,
                    "docsExamined": 2,
                    "alreadyHasObj": 0,
                    "inputStage": {
                        "stage": "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned": 2,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                        "works": 3,
                        "advanced": 2,
                        "needTime": 0,
                        "needYield": 0,
                        "saveState": 0,
                        "restoreState": 0,
                        "isEOF": 1,
                        "invalidates": 0,
                        "keyPattern": {
                            "read_at": 1
                        },
                        "indexName": "read_at_1",
                        "isMultiKey": false,
                        "multiKeyPaths": {
                            "read_at": []
                        },
                        "isUnique": false,
                        "isSparse": false,
                        "isPartial": false,
                        "indexVersion": 2,
                        "direction": "forward",
                        "indexBounds": {
                            "read_at": [
                                "(new Date(1557993357799), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined": 2,
                        "seeks": 1,
                        "dupsTested": 0,
                        "dupsDropped": 0,
                        "seenInvalidated": 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nReturned": 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                "totalKeysExamined": 2,
                "totalDocsExamined": 2,
                "executionStages": {
                    "stage": "FETCH",
                    "filter": {
                        "read_at": {
                            "$gt": ISODate("2019-05-16T07:55:57.799Z")
                        }
                    },
                    "nReturned": 1,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                    "works": 3,
                    "advanced": 1,
                    "needTime": 1,
                    "needYield": 0,
                    "saveState": 0,
                    "restoreState": 0,
                    "isEOF": 1,
                    "invalidates": 0,
                    "docsExamined": 2,
                    "alreadyHasObj": 0,
                    "inputStage": {
                        "stage": "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned": 2,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
                        "works": 3,
                        "advanced": 2,
                        "needTime": 0,
                        "needYield": 0,
                        "saveState": 0,
                        "restoreState": 0,
                        "isEOF": 1,
                        "invalidates": 0,
                        "keyPattern": {
                            "notifiable.$id": 1,
                            "notifiable.$ref": 1,
                            "created_at": -1,
                            "updated_at": -1
                        },
                        "indexName": "notifiable.$id_1_notifiable.$ref_1_created_at_-1_updated_at_-1",
                        "isMultiKey": false,
                        "multiKeyPaths": {
                            "notifiable.$id": [],
                            "notifiable.$ref": [],
                            "created_at": [],
                            "updated_at": []
                        },
                        "isUnique": false,
                        "isSparse": false,
                        "isPartial": false,
                        "indexVersion": 2,
                        "direction": "forward",
                        "indexBounds": {
                            "notifiable.$id": [
                                "[ObjectId('5cdd172ac1136c1bdc06bdf2'), ObjectId('5cdd172ac1136c1bdc06bdf2')]"
                            ],
                            "notifiable.$ref": [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ],
                            "created_at": [
                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                            ],
                            "updated_at": [
                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined": 2,
                        "seeks": 1,
                        "dupsTested": 0,
                        "dupsDropped": 0,
                        "seenInvalidated": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "ok": 1,
    "operationTime": Timestamp(1557996666, 2),
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": Timestamp(1557996666, 2),
        "signature": {
            "hash": BinData(0, "hDKqoIo9DL71/n8vfgSDS3czZ9c="),
            "keyId": NumberLong("6685056801689305089")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the `orders` example from https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/core/index-intersection/ and got the same results. And because [MongoDB currently doesn't allow using multiple indices as a hint](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22741), I cannot enforce MongoDB to use both the indices for my query. To make matters worse, it seems previously `explain(true)` would always include something like `"cursor" : "Complex Plan"` when there were available index intersection plans ([Why doesn't MongoDB use index intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786853/why-doesnt-mongodb-use-index-intersection)) but now this info has been removed.

So how can I know, when there are enough data perhaps, whether an intersection of indices would be used or not?

PS: I'm using MongoDB Atlas which is running MongoDB 4.0.9 Enterprise atm.

Comment: If you have some more complex case in mind, maybe describe it here. There's likely a better schema design that will help without index intersection

Comment: @NicCottrell That'd be a totally _different_ question. The problem here is, where you can just assume I've got a schema and need to run queries which an index intersection can support perfectly and even more cheaply, how I can confirm that the intersection can indeed support my query although it's not always chosen by the planner. The question is _not_ just about my example specifically but validating index intersections in general.

Comment: @NicCottrell I understand index intersection's got its limitations and certainly not a solution for everything. But the function is there, and because it can be an intersection of prefixes from (usually 2) compound indices, obviously it can help lowering the design complexity. I don't understand why you kept trying to steer my wheel away from it and it's actually off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a method to verify index intersections in general.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "verify" but since MongoDB uses *actual times* running a query in parallel with different index options, you need real-world data to evaluate indexes properly. Your question seems to include a small amount of dummy data, but you should use something like [mgeneratejs](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mgeneratejs) to create a large amount of realistic data, so that the index selection mechanism has something to work with. Then you can run "[all plans execution](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#allplansexecution-mode)" mode, i.e. `.explain("allPlansExecution")` to see all indexes compared on the same query and data.

However, it's very unlikely that an index intersection is going to be performant in your use case. I would say that you'd be much better off just creating another index:

`{"notifiable.$id": 1, "read_at": 1}`

Yes, another index will require some more disk space, and slightly more work with each write operation.

Comment: First of all, this doesn't seem to be an answer to my question... Secondly, there are a number of more complicated scenarios where I'd need ~10 compound indices each to cover all my queries even if I try to merge those that share common prefixes. Not only will it be a matter of disk space, but also a concern of insufficient RAM and overly complex design.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make it clearer... Take a simple index as an example, if I run something like `db.coll.find({ field_1: "foo" }).hint("completely_unrelated_index").explain(true)` (btw true=allPlansExecution here), fields such as `nReturned` `works` `docsExamined` in the response would clearly indicate that the index is not working for this query (so maybe I need to fix my index definitions), even with only a few docs in the collection. Now I need the same thing for intersections.

Comment: Perhaps this is simply impossible before https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22741 is implemented. I may need to figure out some time to go through some source code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll find that when you force index intersection you'll find query times _increase_ since they're a complex way to achieve a query.

Comment: How is that related to my question?! Of course the query time's gonna increase cos I've got only a few docs in the example but it may help reduce the time when a dataset grows. That's why I kept emphasising that the question is about "verifying" the correctness of an intersection but not getting to the bottom why it wasn't used by the planner in my example.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at your explain execution stats output, you can see that the index that it used worked really well -- using a compound index here rather than an index intersection seems like a good decision from the query planner:

```
    "executionStats": {
        "executionSuccess": true,
        "nReturned": 1,
        "executionTimeMillis": 0,
        "totalKeysExamined": 2,
        "totalDocsExamined": 2,
...
    }
```

Index intersections get used when there's absolutely no better option, most of the data is on disk, and you don't have any indexes that are remotely selective.

If you want to look at this locally, you can create collections where `{a: 1}` and `{b: 1}` aren't very selective, and you can see mongo consider and reject using these as index intersections.

```js
const toInsert = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { toInsert.push({a: i % 10, b: i % 9 }); }
db.test_coll.createIndex({a: 1});
db.test_coll.createIndex({b: 1});
db.test_coll.find({a: 100, b: 100}).explain()
```

And looking in the rejected plans:

```
...
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "b" : {
                                "$eq" : 100
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "a" : {
                                "$eq" : 100
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "AND_SORTED",
                    "inputStages" : [
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "b" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "b_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "b" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "b" : [
                                    "[100.0, 100.0]"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "a" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "a_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "a" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "a" : [
                                    "[100.0, 100.0]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: This is not helpful at all and not even an answer to my question. I clearly mentioned I understood why index intersection was not preferred by query planner. Currently after consulting 1 index there's often only 1 or 2 documents left hence of course the planner didn't even bother checking another index. BUT, without dumping tons of junk into my dev DB and guessing the planner behaviour, how do I confirm whether an intersection **can potentially** support a query or not and jump in to help when needed?

Comment: For the case that you described, mongo could theoretically use an index intersection, but in practice it won't -- index intersections really are a last resort. The index needs to have really low cardinality, and most of the collection needs to be on disk. I added some more details about how to reproduce this locally

Comment: Again, this question is not about any specific schema or query, I'm looking for a way to confirm the **correctness** of a **potential** index intersection. Just like what I do for my other queries and compound indices, every time a query gets even slightly complex, I go run an `explain()` to avoid human errors. If my test data make the planner choose a different index than the one I'd like to verify, I use `hint()` to enforce it. BUT this works only for single index setups, I now need an equivalent one for intersections.

Comment: Human errors are harder to avoid for index intersections, especially when `sort()` mixes in, one has to keep in mind that the `sort()` field needs to be part of the index intersection as well. This is why I need a stable way to check the correctness of intersections, even they may never be actually used in production. But sure if you can prove that your test data generating can stably reproduce the result for any schema and query I'd say it's a sub-optimal solution, as `explain()` `hint()` doesn't require that.