# Can MongoDB utilize wildcard indexes for intersection?

Tags: mongodb

Say for instance I have documents such as:

```
{
   account: ...,
   site: ...,
   property1: ...,
   property2: ...
}
```

I have an index on `account, site` and a wildcard on `property1, property2`.

Can MongoDB optimise the query by utilizing index intersection with the wildcard index when querying for `{account: 1234, $or: [{property1: 345}, {property2: 345}]}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, yes -- wildcard indexes should behave the same as sparse single key indexes (which could allow for index intersections).

Practically speaking, I'd guess no -- using an index intersection only speeds up a query in rare situations ([Why doesn't MongoDB use index intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786853/why-doesnt-mongodb-use-index-intersection) has some great details). It's always worth checking out your $explain output to see what query plans it's considering and what it's actually doing.

Comment: Thanks. I also checked out that article as it is related. I'm accepting your answer